# Integrating uber API(deeplinking) on Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, deep-linking, uber-api

Hi I want to integrate Ride with uber button on my APP. I made get request to [api](https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/estimates/price) with parameters

```
'server_token': 'ma***********************u',
'start_latitude',
'start_longitude',
'end_latitude' 
'end_longitude'.
```

and I got the response:

```
{
 "result": {
 "prices": [
    {
     "currency_code": "INR",
     "display_name": "uberGO",
    "distance": 18.45,
    "duration": 3503,
    "estimate": "₹559-720",
    "high_estimate": 720,
    "localized_display_name": "uberGO",
    "low_estimate": 559,
    "minimum": 60,
    "product_id": "c8170d76-b67c-44b1-8c26-5f45541434d2",
    "surge_multiplier": 2
  },
  {
    "currency_code": "INR",
    "display_name": "uberGO",
    "distance": 18.45,
    "duration": 3503,
    "estimate": "₹559-719",
    "high_estimate": 719,
    "localized_display_name": "uberGO",
    "low_estimate": 559,
    "minimum": 60,
    "product_id": "bc46ccfe-de64-4cad-b63a-7cf48e649a3e",
    "surge_multiplier": 2
  },
  {
    "currency_code": "INR",
    "display_name": "uberX",
    "distance": 18.45,
    "duration": 3503,
    "estimate": "₹834-1,069",
    "high_estimate": 1069,
    "localized_display_name": "uberX",
    "low_estimate": 834,
    "minimum": 80,
    "product_id": "4da6a747-e0be-4f56-a3c7-3f30f22bf86d",
    "surge_multiplier": 2.4
  },
  {
    "currency_code": "INR",
    "display_name": "uberGO",
    "distance": 18.45,
    "duration": 3503,
    "estimate": "₹834-1,069",
    "high_estimate": 1069,
    "localized_display_name": "uberGO",
    "low_estimate": 834,
    "minimum": 80,
    "product_id": "18656d0e-cc1b-4aa6-8146-92e605626caa",
    "surge_multiplier": 2.4
  },
  {
    "currency_code": "INR",
    "display_name": "uberXL",
    "distance": 18.45,
    "duration": 3503,
    "estimate": "₹1,646-2,099",
    "high_estimate": 2099,
    "localized_display_name": "uberXL",
    "low_estimate": 1646,
    "minimum": 125,
    "product_id": "2ea18da2-bcf0-4df7-a7b8-a827e9945322",
    "surge_multiplier": 3.4
  },
  {
    "currency_code": "INR",
    "display_name": "uberXL",
    "distance": 18.45,
    "duration": 3503,
    "estimate": "₹1,646-2,099",
    "high_estimate": 2099,
    "localized_display_name": "uberXL",
    "low_estimate": 1646,
    "minimum": 125,
    "product_id": "a4404842-e40a-471b-a7a5-13da3551e94f",
    "surge_multiplier": 3.4
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

Now I added this code on onclicklisteners of buttons:

```
String uri = "uber://?client_id=eFrzgz_2Du2KYUXIi3MKaNOWtxo3i77K&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=37.775818&pickup[longitude]=-122.418028&pickup[nickname]=UberHQ&pickup[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103&dropoff[latitude]=37.802374&dropoff[longitude]=-122.405818&dropoff[nickname]=Coit%20Tower&dropoff[formatted_address]=1%20Telegraph%20Hill%20Blvd%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094133&product_id=a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

On clicking these buttons, it button redirects to uber APP with correct src and dst, but it's not picking correct uber category, like UberX, UberGo, UberL, etc. It always chooses default category. How to customize it to level that user just need to click a single button to book the cab.

Comment: working completely fine on my case

Comment: What you did?  can you share your code?

Comment: i did nothing same code

Answer (score 1):

The [sample data](https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk/tree/master/sdk/src/test/resources/deeplinkuris) used by the deep linking tests in the uber-rides-sdk for Android shows the same parameters for the intent that you send, so it should work.

> uber:?action=setPickup&client_id=clientId&product_id=productId&pickup%5Blatitude%5D=32.1234&pickup%5Blongitude%5D=-122.3456&pickup%5Bnickname%5D=pickupNick&pickup%5Bformatted_address%5D=Pickup%20Address&dropoff%5Blatitude%5D=32.5678&dropoff%5Blongitude%5D=-122.6789&dropoff%5Bnickname%5D=pickupNick&dropoff%5Bformatted_address%5D=Dropoff%20Address

In the tests data I see that they also [URL/percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the keys and values (e.g. pickup%5Blatitude%5D=32.1234), however in the [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/deep-linking#section-launching-the-uber-app) they don't.
Try to encode the data URI and retry.

Maybe you send the intent to the Uber app too late? That is, after the product id (the Uber car) no longer exists on the server, so the Uber app will not select it either.

Are those products returned from the [sandbox API](https://developer.uber.com/docs/sandbox) or the production API endpoints?

Can you validate the product id first by making a request to the [GET /v1/products/{product_id}](https://developer.uber.com/docs/v1-products-details) and ensure you get 200 OK HTTP response status code and the correct product details in the response body?